# How to resolve a 'Bad packet length' error in SSH.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp

I'm trying to upload files via SFTP, using [SSH.NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/).  `SFTPClient.Connect()` throws an SshConnectionException with the message, "Bad packet length 1302334341."  This is my code:

```
static void Main()
{
try
{
 SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(server, 22, userID, password);
 sftp.Connect();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
}
```

I saw in another [discussion](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/271671) that this probably has to do with encryption.  I'm using AES, and I have a host key.  I don't understand how to enter the encryption, though.  Based on that discussion, I was playing with this:

```
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo(server, 22, userID, password);
connectionInfo.Encryptions.Clear();
connectionInfo.Encryptions.Add("aes","ssh-rsa 2048 11:22:34:d4:56:d6:78:90:01:22:6b:46:34:54:55:8a")
```

I know that's not the right set of arguments to pass to Encryptions.Add(), but I'm a little lost with using this library; can you help me figure out how to set the encryption properly (assuming that's the problem)?

Comment: Solved, in [this discussion](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/358307).  I needed to remove encryptions using `foreach (var d in connectionInfo.Encryptions.Where(p => p.Key != "aes128-cbc").ToList())
                {
                    connectionInfo.Encryptions.Remove(d.Key);
                }`, substituting in whichever encryption I intend to use.

Comment: You can put your comment as an answer - helped me, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, in [this discussion](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/358307). I needed to remove encryptions using

```
foreach (var d in connectionInfo.Encryptions.Where(p => p.Key != "aes128-cbc").ToList()) 
{
 connectionInfo.Encryptions.Remove(d.Key); 
}
```

substituting in whichever encryption I intend to use