# ssh.net sftp Bad Packet length / open SSH version 2 RSA?

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp

I'm new to sftp and i'm trying to get a c# program to send a file via sftp to a remote server not under my control.

Using code like:

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(FTPAddress, FTPName, FTPPassword))
                    {
                        ConnectionInfo myCI = sftp.ConnectionInfo;

                        sftp.Connect(); // <<<< Exception on connect

                        sftp.UploadFile(sftp_ms, FileName,true);

                        sftp.Disconnect();
                    }
```

I receive a "Bad packet length" exception.

Google searching reveals that a bad packet length is likely to be a mismatch in encryption formats but I don't know how to resolve that.

The specification i've received from the client is:

```
Keys must be in Open SSH version 2 format RSA format
```

I don't know how to do this. A previous SO question [How to resolve a 'Bad packet length' error in SSH.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886665/how-to-resolve-a-bad-packet-length-error-in-ssh-net) has a link to sshnet.codeplex discussion where removing the encryption keys that you don't want solved the issue for that poster.

I can see 16 entries in ssh.net's connectioninfo class but none of them state open SSH version 2 RSA though one of them may very well be (i've tried googling).

I have tried the ip, name and password i've been given with filezilla and I connect no problems; so filezilla somehow uses the correct encryption; I don't know how to tell what it's using.

Help ?

Andrew

Comment: What is the type of FTPPassword?  It could be using the wrong overload for the ctor.  Also, are you sure the remote server accepts username/password auth and not public key auth?

Comment: all strings; but if that was a problem for the overload it would error on the construction, not the connection ? As for remote server, when I put that IP, username and password into filezilla, it makes a successful connection and I can then also transfer files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two different problems here. If you're getting the bad packet length problem, then you probably have to follow the guide in the [ssh.net Codeplex](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/358307) discussion to resolve the negotiation. This should resolve the establishing of the initial connection.

If you're required to use an ssh private key for connection, then you have to use one of the constructors that takes an array of PrivateKey objects. One of the constructors for a PrivateKey takes a stream, and you can convert the private key string to the stream using code like:

```
var privKey = new PrivateKey(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.getBytes(sshPrivateKeyString)));
var sftpclient = new SftpClient(FTPAddress, FTPName, new PrivateKeyFile[] { privKey });
```

Other mechanisms are to use an explicit PrivateKeyConnectionInfo instance:

```
var privKey = new PrivateKey(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.getBytes(sshPrivateKeyString)));
var privConnInfo = new PrivateKeyConnectionInfo(FTPAddress, FTPName, privKey);
var sftpClient = new SftpClient(privConnInfo);
```

Comment: Late reply sorry; more info for future searchers: from what I understand if you use sftp with username/password, you don't need public/private key because authentication is by user/pass; public/private needed where there is no user/password logon. I was erroneously trying to do both