# SFTP Upload via SSH.Net crashes after a few thousand files

Tags: c#, ssh.net

For an archiving routine I need to upload files and their respective folder-structure to an sftp. In the testcase I'm running its about 36.000 PDF-Files, 400-500 KB each, with a .xml and a .ok file each, so about 108.000 Files total. 
Issue is, after around 3.500 PDF files, or 10.500 total files, the program produces a "Bad packet length" exception and terminates.

This is where the upload takes place

```
SftpClient client = new SftpClient("rDir", 22000, "user", "password");
client.Connect();
client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
UploadDirectory(client, upFilePath, @"/");
client.Disconnect();
```

the UploadDirectory function looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> infos =
                new DirectoryInfo(localPath).EnumerateFileSystemInfos();
            foreach (FileSystemInfo info in infos)
            {
                if (info.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
                {
                    string subPath = remotePath + "/" + info.Name;
                    if (!client.Exists(subPath))
                    {
                        client.CreateDirectory(subPath);
                    }
                    UploadDirectory(client, info.FullName, remotePath + "/" + info.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(info.FullName, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        client.UploadFile(fileStream, remotePath + "/" + info.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The code doesnt produce a timeout that I know of, the connection is stable and yet after only around 10.000 files it encounters a "Bad packet length" error that I do not really understand from the looks of it.

Do I need to change BufferSizes or am I missing a crucial argument?

Comment: Does it always crash on the same file or number of files?  Are you able to inspect the server's logs to see if there's anything noteworthy in there?  That same error is discussed in [How to resolve a 'Bad packet length' error in SSH.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10886665/150605) and [ssh.net sftp Bad Packet length / open SSH version 2 RSA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15329684/150605), although in both questions the exception is thrown in the call to `Connect()`.

Comment: @BACON it always crashes at around the same number of files, around 10.500 combined pdf, xml and ok files. That equals to almost exactly an hour of runtime each time. I can not look at the server's logs however.

Comment: What version of SSH.NET? Doesn't the server trigger re-key after one hour?

Comment: Im using the latest version. And, I actually dont know if it does.

Comment: So can you connect with some SSH client, like PuTTY, and keep it running for one hour and then check its log file (Event Log in case of PuTTY)?